# Ribbon control switching tab keytip needs to be pressed twice

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control

When we switch from one tab to another using keyboard shortcut, why key needs to be pressed twice. Please refer this [project](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/0b73e1/ribbon-control-in-wpf-4-5/).

[image]

Comment: Which key, the shortcut key, or are you using like tab+space or something like that?

Comment: shortcut key 'H' to move to home. after alt press 'H' need to be pressed twice